# How to use HTML in Apexcharts data label

Tags: javascript, html, apexcharts

[image]

I wanna use the HTML tag in one data label of ApexCharts.
For now, ApexCharts is only providing formatter function to customize the data label, but only can use the string.

I know if I use the array value in formatter function, I can show them in 2 lines.
But need to show 2 lines on the left side, show 1 line on the right side.
Also with the array value in formatter function, I cannot set the wording space according to the width of the red bar.

```html
formatter: (val, opt)=> {
    return ["first line", "second line"];
},
```

Is there any way to use the HTML tag in ApexCharts Data Label?